# Using OpenStreetMap API, getting errors on the jar file? NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, openstreetmap

I am trying to create an application to test how to use `OpenStreetMaps` API but when I insert the jar file I get errors saying `NoClassDefFoundError`

stack trace

```
07-05 13:35:43.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9235): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-05 13:35:43.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9235): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
07-05 13:35:43.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9235):     at com.example.osm.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
07-05 13:35:43.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9235):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
07-05 13:35:43.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9235):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
07-05 13:35:43.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9235):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
07-05 13:35:43.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9235):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
07-05 13:35:43.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9235):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
07-05 13:35:43.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9235):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
07-05 13:35:43.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9235):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-05 13:35:43.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9235):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-05 13:35:43.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9235):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
07-05 13:35:43.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9235):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-05 13:35:43.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9235):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-05 13:35:43.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9235):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
07-05 13:35:43.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9235):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-05 13:35:43.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9235):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-05 13:35:43.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9235): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
07-05 13:35:43.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9235):     at org.osmdroid.views.MapView.<clinit>(MapView.java:64)
07-05 13:35:43.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9235):     ... 15 more
```

my Activity is as simple as this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    MapView mapView = new MapView(this,256); //fails
    mapView.setClickable(true);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    setContentView(mapView);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}


}
```

it fails as soon as it trys to create the mapview, is there another jar file I am suppose to have? currently I have `osmdroid-android-3.0.8.jar`, `osmdroid-packager-3.0.8.jar` and `osmdroid-third-party-3.0.8.jar` though i probably dont need the last 2 to actually create the map.

any help would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need one more jar

```
NoClassDefFoundError: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
```

gives you the clue

slf4j-android-1.5.8.jar is the jar you need

Edit:

It seems like there's a later (1.6.6) version now, available at:
[latest slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/download.html)

Comment: ok so I downloaded the zip file and now what file do I need out of there because there are a bunch of different jar files, none of which say `slf4j-android`

Comment: nevermind I got it its the `slf4j-api-1.6.6.jar` file that you need just in-case anyone else runs into this problem

Comment: @tyczj the jar you mentioned didn't work for me and created follow-up errors. Instead I downloaded the required jar from here: http://www.slf4j.org/android/ namely: slf4j-android-1.5.8.jar

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need one more jar for the error  `NoClassDefFoundError: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory` from this

http://www.slf4j.org/android/ and the name of the jar is `slf4j-android-1.6.1-RC1.jar [sha1]`